# Multiple AJAX Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

quiero hacer un menú en mi pagina y que cargue distintas entradas según que opción se elija. El problema que tengo es que, tengo una función que atiende las peticiones AJAX pero no se como atender otras, o sea, no se como mostrar otro tipo de entradas.

Les dejo el codigo que tengo:

functions.php:

```
function my_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js', get_theme_file_uri( 'js/eventos.js'), array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_js', 'ajax_var', array(
        'url'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce'  => wp_create_nonce( 'my-ajax-nonce' ),
        'action' => 'event-list'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts' );

function my_event_list_cb() {

    $nonce = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nonce'] );

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-ajax-nonce' ) ) {
        die ( 'Busted!');
    }

    echo '<h5>MUSICA</h5> <div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="musica" cantidad="3"]' ); 
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<h5>DEPORTES</h5><div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="deportes" cantidad="3"]' );
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<h5>TEATRO</h5><div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="teatro" cantidad="3"]' ); 
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<h5>DANZA</h5><div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="danza" cantidad="3"]' ); 
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<h5>NIÑOS</h5><div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="niños" cantidad="3"]' ); 
    echo '</div>';

    echo'<h5>FOLKLORE Y TRADICION</h5><div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="folklore" cantidad="3"]' );
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<h5>CLASICA Y LIRICA</h5><div class="div--categoria">';
    echo do_shortcode( '[promociones categoria="clasica" cantidad="3"]' ); 
    echo '</div>';


    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_event-list', 'my_event_list_cb' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_event-list', 'my_event_list_cb' );
```

Cliente (eventos.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#destacados").on("click", function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_var.url,
            hook: 'event-list',
            data: "action=" + ajax_var.action + "&nonce=" + ajax_var.nonce,
            success: function(result){
                $('.div--publicaciones').html(result);
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

> **Aclaración:** Hasta ahora, al hacer click en "destacados" realiza una
>   solicitud AJAX y me devuelve una serie de entradas. Lo que yo quiero
>   saber es, que tengo que programar en functions.php para que cuando
>   haga click en "nuevos" me devuelva las entradas nuevas y no las
>   "destacadas"

Comment: incluir una variable en el post y luego según esa variable mostras los nuevos o los destacados

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo solucione de esa forma, la verdad no sabia si era una buena practica, pero no me quedaba otra.

Comment: mientras sanitizes toda entrada, verifiques el nonce y los permisos públicos ( sobre todo en la variante `no_priv`) es la forma mas simple y genérica de hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias @aloMalbarez